# All icons disappear after wake-up

Tags: 22.04, suspend, icons, application-switcher, wakeup

Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS on ThinkPad X270.

After putting the machine to sleep mode, when the laptop is woken up, all icons in the menu sidebar and in the Show Applications panel disappear. The only thing that works is the application that has been running when the laptop was put into sleep. No option to switch between apps using keyboard shortcut Alt-Tab. Only possibility to use another application is to restart the laptop.

Any ideas what is wrong and how it could be fixed?